# Why keyboard control stopped working in vb.net when i added checkbox

Tags: vb.net

Here the code all was working peacefully and without any error but when i added a checkbox to my form keys are stopped working

```
 Dim Lefty, Righty As Boolean
 Private Sub Player_ctrl_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Player_ctrl.Tick
        Dim Speed As Integer = 23

        If Lefty And Player1.Left > Me.Left Then
            testlabel.Text += 1
            Player1.Left -= Speed
        ElseIf Righty And Player1.Left + Player1.Width < Me.Width Then
            Player1.Left += Speed
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub MainGame_KeyDown(sender As Object, e As KeyEventArgs) Handles Me.KeyDown
        Select Case e.KeyCode
            Case Keys.Left
                Lefty = True
            Case Keys.Right
                Righty = True
        End Select


    End Sub



    Private Sub MainGame_KeyUp(sender As Object, e As KeyEventArgs) Handles Me.KeyUp
        Lefty = False
        Righty = False

    End Sub
```

Any fixes please?

Comment: Have you set the form's `KeyPreview` to `true`?